# How can I display buttons without space between them on Android?

Tags: android, button, chess

I want to make a chess app on Android and I'm trying to use Buttons to make a chessboard. The problem is that when I try to display the buttons there is space between them, and I don't know how to remove it. I've tried removing the padding, the margin, etc. but nothing works. Here's the xml I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#B5651D"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/first"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#B5651D"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_below="@id/first"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#B5651D"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is what the app looks like:

[image]

Comment: Actually the buttons are not designed for this purpose. You can use recyclerview or gridview (is old) if your content changes dynamically; or you can use layouts like tablelayout + tablerow/column combination or a better way gridlayout + cardview combination.

Answer (score 0):

The buttons are not meant to do this, You should use RecyclerView, or a GridView.

But still if you want to do it through buttons, just use a Linearlayout with weightsum and then  buttons inside the linearlayout with layout_weight, and also set background of buttons as pure square, because by default buttons have  slightly curved corners.